# MBP first generation Service Battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My MacBook Pro is throwing me a message "Service Battery" and [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) tells me I have 4007 mAh instead of 5450 mAh.

Is there a way to pump it back up or is that impossible?

I was looking around on the Internet but the Apple Store does not display a built-in MacBook Pro 13 inch battery.

Should I replace mine? And if so, where is the best place to look for since Apple does not have them theirselves?

[image: Coconut Battery]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Battery degradation is normal, and seeing that your battery is almost 4 years old has went through 820 cycles, you battery retention is still quite good. Degradation of battery is irreversible.

If you really want to get a fresh battery, you can take it to an Apple store. It'll cost somewhere around $150.

Apple [replace defective notebook battery](http://www.apple.com/batteries/replacements.html) only within 3 years of purchase with AppleCare, so you wouldn't get that benefit.

Comment: Can you tell me @Enrico why my MBP 13" is not in Apple's list on the site you've provided me?

Comment: @Robuust it falls under the general "Notebook Owners" heading. The link below that are for notebook that has replaceable batteries. They can just buy new batteries from those links.